# Remember place scrolling on each page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 files besides the main HTML: test.html, test2.html and test3.html.
When you press one of the buttons a page is loaded. So I want the scroll position to be saved between page loads. Example: you load page test and then scroll to the middle, load page test2, scroll to the end, load back page test and it should be in the middle.

How could I archive this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery load() Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button1").click(function() {
        $("#box").load("test.html");
      });
      $("#button2").click(function() {
        $("#box").load("test2.html");
      });
      $("#button3").click(function() {
        $("#box").load("test3.html");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position: fixed;"><button id="button1">test</button> <button id="button2">test2</button> <button id="button3">test3</button> </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="box">
    <h2>Click button to load new content inside DIV box</h2>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Please reformulate so we can understand what you want.

Comment: does the current code load any of the html pages?

Comment: when i load test.html in div id="box" and i scrolling my page to middle and i load test2.html and i return to test.html i want it be in position When I left
@NelsonTeixeira

Comment: Initially it will carry the contents of the (box) and when you press on (test) will exhibit the contents test.html @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt

Comment: Let me see if I understood: You want to save the position of the pages once you loaded one and scrolled it. Example: you load page one then scroll to the middle, load page 2, scroll to the end, load back page one and it should be in the middle. Is that it ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Yep

Comment: Yes, exactly, the problem is when I carry the first and pass to the middle, and when I carry a second page to the end and when you return to the first page at the end of it as well @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: I recommend adding 3 global variables and storing the scrolltop values on scroll event and set the respective scroll positions on button clicks. Got it?

Comment: But I do not want it and liquefied storage .. It just work (jquery) and I saw a lot of sites running the piece @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here's what you need to do, if I understand your problem correctly:

you re gonna save the current position of the page in a variable before loading new one. And set scroll position to the value you saved when you call that page again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery load() Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      var pos = {}
      var lastLoaded
      $('.btn').click(function(e) {
        v = e.target.value
        pos[lastLoaded] = $('body').scrollTop()
        $("#box").load(v);
        lastLoaded = v
        if(pos[v])
          $('body').scrollTop(pos[v])
        else
          $('body').scrollTop(0)
      })
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position: fixed;">
    <button class="btn" id="button1" value="test1.html">test</button>
    <button class="btn" id="button2" value="test2.html">test2</button>
    <button class="btn" id="button3" value="test3.html">test3</button>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="box">
    <h2>Click button to load new content inside DIV box</h2>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira It's not working only in your code. Because your buttons do not have a `value` attribute, which is used as key to store the scrolling position for each page in `pos` object. https://jsfiddle.net/x12y0uju/1/

Comment: Your example, didn't work for me also. Have you really tested it ?

Comment: yeah, I did. the jsfiddle you posted didnt work for me too at first, but when I added the value attribute it worked.

Comment: What I meant is that I tested it with you edition (added value attributes) in https://jsfiddle.net/x12y0uju/1/ and it's not working for me. What browser are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 56.0. But I dont think there is something in the code that may cause compatibility issues

Comment: Neither do I, but the scroll positions aren't being maintained for each page, and if you pressed all 3 the first gets altered

Comment: But there is a problem is when do I download page (test.html) when I change the contents of the page (test.html) and do I reload the page does not load new information
@mockingjay

Comment: I think I got what happens there. Open the DevTools (F12 in chrome), go to network tab and check out "Disable cache". (you need to leave DevTools open while you're testing you code.)

Comment: ohh any user using my site must do that ... pleas give me correct solution @mockingjay

Comment: Basically that is not the problem you posed in your question. You may want to ask about that in a separate/new question (or just google it). Please consider marking back my question as "most helpful in finding your solution"

Comment: Did not take advantage of your answer is anything but I'll accept your answer
@mockingjay

Answer (score 0):

This is onde of many ways to do what you want

```js
function currPos() { // crossbrowser get actual scroll position
  return window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

function loadAndSavePosition(button) {
  var pos = currPos(); // obtain current position
  if (page) // if there is a loaded page, save the position of the actual page
    scrollData[page] = pos;
  page = button.target.innerText;
  // simulates page load
  h2.innerHTML = (button.target.innerText + ' ').repeat(10000);
  if (scrollData[page]) { //if there is an already save value ...
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollData[page]); // ...move to that position...
  } else {  // ... or to the top if there isn't.
    scrollData[page] = 0;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}

var h2 = document.getElementById('h2');
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
var page = ''; // loaded page
var scrollData = {}; // object for saving the page scroll positions

// associate onclick event to the loadAndSavePosition function
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button')).forEach(
  button => button.onclick = loadAndSavePosition);
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed;">
  <button id="button1">test</button>
  <button id="button2">test2</button>
  <button id="button3">test3</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="box">
  <h2 id='h2'>Click button to load new content inside DIV box</h2>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5dkL5nn/7/

Comment: thank you for answer but where are my page test.html where putted

Comment: substitute `h2.innerHTML = (button.target.innerText + ' ').repeat(10000);` by `$("#box").load(button.target.innerText + ".html");`. But the main thing is understanding how I did the scroll postion saving and reposition, so you can create you own version of it. I can't load pages here, so I simulated it.

Comment: ok give me ready code from that part with test.html and i will loaded ??

Comment: didn't understand your english

Answer (score 0):

To remember scroll of all pages use this code

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    let UrlsObj = localStorage.getItem('rememberScroll');
    let ParseUrlsObj = JSON.parse(UrlsObj);
    let windowUrl = window.location.href;

    if (ParseUrlsObj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    ParseUrlsObj.forEach(function (el) {
        if (el.url === windowUrl) {
            let getPos = el.scroll;
            $(window).scrollTop(getPos);
        }
    });

});

function RememberScrollPage(scrollPos) {

    let UrlsObj = localStorage.getItem('rememberScroll');
    let urlsArr = JSON.parse(UrlsObj);

    if (urlsArr == null) {
        urlsArr = [];
    }

    if (urlsArr.length == 0) {
        urlsArr = [];
    }

    let urlWindow = window.location.href;
    let urlScroll = scrollPos;
    let urlObj = {url: urlWindow, scroll: scrollPos};
    let matchedUrl = false;
    let matchedIndex = 0;

    if (urlsArr.length != 0) {
        urlsArr.forEach(function (el, index) {

            if (el.url === urlWindow) {
                matchedUrl = true;
                matchedIndex = index;
            }

        });

        if (matchedUrl === true) {
            urlsArr[matchedIndex].scroll = urlScroll;
        } else {
            urlsArr.push(urlObj);
        }


    } else {
        urlsArr.push(urlObj);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('rememberScroll', JSON.stringify(urlsArr));

}

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    let topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log('Scrolling', topScroll);
    RememberScrollPage(topScroll);
});
```